# How can I access this JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json, web

I'm trying to access some JSON data that I got through an ajax call. I'm not sure how to access this data now though. I want to extract the "test" portion out of the json. Could someone please help me out with this

[Image of current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htA7l.png)

code sample:

```
$(".test").on("click", function() {
var dialogID = $(this).attr("id");
console.log(dialogID);
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.php?id=" + dialogID,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("error");
  }
});
```

Comment: You are required to display the code here. An image means you are forcing us to type what little code you show ourselves by hand. Please do that work for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the ajax data is stored in a variable called 'data'

```
data['DATA'][0][0];
```

If you look at the developer console, you'll notice that 'test' in an item in array at index 0. That array is at index 0 of another array called DATA. DATA is an array in the object returned by the AJAX call.

You can see all the data types next to the variable names in the developer console, i.e 'COLUMNS: Array[1]' on the second line tells you that COLUMNS is an array of length 1.

Comment: Glad I could help!